Can I batch delete followers and Likes on my Facebook Business Page?
I want to remove thousands of Followers and Likes from my Facebook Business Page. The only way I see to do this is to "block" accounts, but I would have to do each one individually.
Is there a way to batch delete Followers and Likes?
